# How can I remove everything past "LIMIT" from a query? (details inside)

Tags: php

I got a few queries built dynamically by my scripts. They usually fit the following template:

```
SELECT ... 
FROM ... 
JOIN ... 
WHERE ... (lots of filters, search conditions, etc. here) ... 
ORDER BY (optional) ... 
LIMIT (optional) ... OFFSET (optional)
```

I want to remove the LIMIT and OFFSET parts from the query. I used

```
$sql_entitati = implode("LIMIT", explode("LIMIT", $sql_entitati, -1));
```

to do it but then it hit me: what if there's no LIMIT in the query and what if the only LIMIT is somewhere in the where clauses?

So my question to you is: How can I safely remove everything after the LIMIT key word, without screwing it up if there's no LIMIT and/or there's a "LIMIT" somewhere in the where clause? All this done in php.

A bit of an edit for clarity:

the algorithm i use:

```
$sql = implode("LIMIT", explode("LIMIT", $sql, -1));
```

Will work on 99% of the cases. The problem occurs when the "LIMIT" key word at the end is missing, AND there is "LIMIT" written somewhere in the conditions. for example:

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE bla = 'SPEED LIMIT' ORDER BY table.a
```

this is the problem i need to tackle.

Solved using the following algorithm (Credit to techfoobar):

```
    $p = strrpos($sql, "LIMIT");
    if($p !== false) {
        $q = strpos($sql, ")", $p);
        $r = strpos($sql, "'", $p);
        $s = strpos($sql, "\"", $p);
        if($q === false && $r === false && $s === false)
            $sql = substr($sql, 0, $p);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do something like:

1. Get the position of the *last* "LIMIT" - store this position in say, `p`
2. Ensure that you do not have a `")"` character after `p` - if so, it is part of some inner query inside a condition etc..
3. Ensure that you do not have a `"'"` character after `p` - if so, it is part of some user input string
4. If steps 2 and 3 are passed, strip off everything after `p`

More hints:

- For step 1 - use `strrpos` for the last occurrence of `LIMIT`
- For steps 2 and 3, use `strpos` with `p` as the search start offset
- For step4, use `substr` to strip off everything after `p`

Comment: Yup, this is what i was looking for. Didn't cross my mind to look for ")" and "'" , kept thinking about key words but none worked since everything after WHERE is optional.

Comment: You should also check for ' " ' along with " ' ".

Answer (score 0):

Get the position of LIMIT, check it exists with !==FALSE then substring.

```
$str = "SELECT X FROM Y JOIN WHERE CONDITIONS ORDER BY ORDERS LIMIT OFFSET";

$pos = strrpos($str,"LIMIT");
if ($pos!==false)
{
$newStr = substr($str,0,$pos);
echo $newStr;
}
```

Comment: I did think of that (and it's how i've implemented it right now), but it's not 100% error proof. The problem is "CONDITIONS"can contain user input, and that may contain the word LIMIT. That's why I used the implode/explode structure, because then I can grab everything until the last LIMIT. But if the query doesn't contain the LIMIT key word, and the CONDITIONS do contain "LIMIT" somewhere, then the algorithm fails and the query becomes unusable.

Comment: sorry yes, use strrpos instead that will find the last occurrence of LIMIT

Comment: EDIT: Sorry, didn't see your last comment. I will use your strrpos idea since it's faster than the implode/explode i'm using.

Comment: Another approach could be changing your dynamic queries so that they always add LIMIT to the query, and for those queries that you dont want any limit you could just put LIMIT 0,<VERY LARGE NUMBER>

Answer (score 0):

Try this aproach

```
$query = '';
$query .= 'SELECT...';
$query .= 'FROM ...';
$query .= 'JOIN ...';
$query .= 'WHERE...';
if ($limit)
{
    $query .= " LIMIT $limit";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you...

```
$str = " SELECT * FROM table WHERE bla = 'SPEED LIMIT' ORDER BY table.a";

$pos = strrpos($str,"LIMIT");
if ($pos!==false)
{
    $ok = 1;
    if(substr_count($str, '"', $pos) % 2 != 0)
    {
        $ok = 0;
    }
    if(substr_count($str, "'", $pos) % 2 != 0)
    {
        $ok = 0;
    }

    if(substr_count($str, ")", $pos) > 0)
    {
        $ok = 0;
    }



    if($ok == 1)
    $str = substr($str,0,$pos);
}

echo $str;
```